# Problems with selects using vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils, vue-material

I'm trying to add a select using vuetify material design but the select doesn't show the options
and if I add the label :`<v-app> </v-app>` works but this one breaks the designs

example: 
[image]

and when I add the label `<v-app> </v-app>` :

[image]

error:

```
[Vuetify] Unable to locate target [data-app]

found in

---> <VMenu>
       <VSelect>
         <IngresaComponent> at src/components/LogIn/ingresa.vue
           <App> at src/App.vue
             <Root>
```

labels:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container up">
      <div class="container down">
        <h3>Inicia Sesion</h3>

        <form method="POST">
          <v-text-field
            v-model="email"
            :error-messages="emailErrors"
            label="Correo"
            required
            @input="$v.email.$touch()"
            @blur="$v.email.$touch()"
          ></v-text-field>

          <v-text-field
            v-model="password"
            :error-messages="passwordErrors"
            :append-icon="show1 ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'"
            :type="show1 ? 'text' : 'password'"
            required
            label="Ingresa contraseña"
            :counter="20"
            @input="$v.password.$touch()"
            @blur="$v.password.$touch()"
            @click:append="show1 = !show1"
          ></v-text-field>

          <v-select :items="options" label="Standard"></v-select>

          <v-btn class="mr-4" @click="submit" :disabled="!isComplete">submit</v-btn>
          <v-btn @click="clear">clear</v-btn>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Quoting the manual - `The v-app component is REQUIRED for all applications. This is the mount point for many of Vuetify's components `

Comment: Could you make a codepen, jsfiddle or codesanbox for this, so we could see the problem our selfs? To solving the styling issue. as Ivo already said the v-app is required.